# General Reel Feedback

Tags: demo-reel, showreel, linear-sound-design, feedback

Hi Everyone,

I've cut together my first linear audio reel and was hoping a few of you might tear it apart before I plaster it all over the place, burn a big stack of DVDs and pound some pavement in 2012.

www.vimeo.com/lucafusi/reel

The intended purpose of the reel is to be a general overview of liner audio work I've done that I could send along as an introduction, or burn to DVD alongside an couple of other clips. Mostly I'd be looking for notes like, this pacing was too quick, I couldn't read X, you don't need to show clip Y, the whole thing was too long, stuff like that.

Specific notes on the quality of the work are helpful, but for the most part these productions are what they are and what I have to work with right now. That said, I could always do a bit of remixing if anything really sticks out.

Thanks so much for watching, I truly appreciate the help.

Luca

Answer (score 1):

Agreed that the Deus Ex end sequence should be cut.  I really don't want to watch a whole trailer, I want to hear samples of your work.

So, I'd lose the end sequence and perhaps an additional 25% or more off the front end as well.

Also, I found myself rewinding to re-read your titles for some sequences.  I like that they stayed up for the entire Gargoyles clip.  I'd consider leaving the titles up for the entirety of each clip, that way whomever is watching can refer to them as the clip progresses.

Comment: Good suggestion on the titles, I was getting that sense, that some of them really rush off too quickly, so maybe I'll just leave 'em up the whole time unless they start getting intrusive. It's not like you're watching a sound reel for the picture anyways..

I'll definitely trim the trailer as well. Thanks very much for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

the reel is very nice, maybe deus ex part at the end should be cut...its very good, but somehow i skipped it at the end, because i heard some great sound work in the beginning of the reel, other than that its good imo;)

Comment: Thanks so much for watching, Linas - I seem to be getting that same piece of advice, so I'll try trimming out a good middle piece of the overall DXHR trailer and just using that. 

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit long, but I like the comparison, something I want to do with some of my work as well, show some more of that maybe?

Comment: The length should be less of an issue once I trim the trailer down, good note. As for the comparisons, I guess you mean the before/after sort of thing I did with the Red Rabbit dialogue (sheriff outside)? I was wondering if that's something that gets done very often in these reels but thought it'd be a nice approach. Maybe I'll give that a little more room to breathe.

Thanks Ed!

Comment: It's something I've been wanting to do with mine, its just getting round to doing it. I think it works, a lot of times you're fixing audio, showing how well you can do it I can imagine can get you a lot of work.